# How to access value of a key which is parent of other keys using IConfiguration object?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, configuration

I have a below configuration json file:

```
{
    "key1": false,
    "key2": "hello world",
    "key3": {
        "f1_somekey": true,
        "f2_somekey": true,
        "f3_cachekey": [
            {
                "s": 1,
                "p": [4, 6, 7, 8, 9]
            },
            {
                "s": 2,
                "p": [5]
            },
            {
                "p": [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I am trying to get each of the keys value from [IConfiguration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1) object but I am confuse on how to get value of `f3_cachekey`? All other keys value I can extract but confuse on `f3_cachekey`.

```
var key1Value = Configuration["key1"];
var key2Value = Configuration["key2"];
var key3_f1Value = Configuration["key3:f1_somekey"];
var key3_f2Value = Configuration["key3:f2_somekey"];
```

I need to make a dictionary of integer as the `key` and HashSet of Integers as the `value` for  `f3_cachekey`.

```
Dictionary<int, HashSet<int>> sToPMapping = new Dictionary<int, HashSet<int>>();
```

I have two cases in `f3_cachekey`:

- I have a combination of `s` and array of `p's`. In the above example - first and second json object of `f3_cachekey`.
- Second is I just have array of `p's` which is third json object. For this case I do have some predefined `s` already stored in another `HashSet` which I will use as the key and each of their `s` value will be all these `p's`.

Is this possible to do? Also if `f3_cachekey` is not present in the above json then I need to make empty dictionary object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configuration with Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration is actually a flat key-value mapping. It’s just the JSON configuration source that allows you to specify the configuration as a hierarchy. Once the file is loaded, the hierarchy is however flattened to direct key to value mapping where the key is the *configuration path*.

For your particular JSON example, the following mappings are available from the configuration:

```
key1                     => false
key2                     => hello 
key3:f1_somekey          => true
key3:f2_somekey          => true
key3:f3_cachekey:0:s     => 1
key3:f3_cachekey:0:p:0   => 4
key3:f3_cachekey:0:p:1   => 6
key3:f3_cachekey:0:p:2   => 7
key3:f3_cachekey:0:p:3   => 8
key3:f3_cachekey:0:p:4   => 9
key3:f3_cachekey:1:s     => 2
key3:f3_cachekey:1:p:0   => 5
key3:f3_cachekey:2:p:0   => 10
key3:f3_cachekey:2:p:1   => 11
key3:f3_cachekey:2:p:2   => 12
key3:f3_cachekey:2:p:3   => 13
key3:f3_cachekey:2:p:4   => 14
```

As you can hopefully see from this, there are no arrays or objects in the configuration object. It’s just a path where `:` separates sections and a single value. Array values are identified by having the array index within the path, e.g. `f3_cachekey:0` for the first element.

This structure makes it very straightforward to support various configuration sources, since they all can create such a key-value mapping, even simple things like environment variables. But this structure also makes it a bit difficult to consume the configuration for non-trivial values. For this reason, there’s the *binder* part of the configuration framework.

If you look at the list above closely, you can see that there is no `key3:f3_cachekey` entry, and also no `key3:f3_cachekey:0` or `key3:f3_cachekey:0:p` entries. That is because at those keys, there isn’t a value itself but rather something other nested structure, an object or an array. In the configuration framework, these are known as *sections* which is basically just a way to talk about a subset of the path. For example, the section with the key `key3:f3_cachekey:0` looks like this:

```
s     => 1
p:0   => 4
p:1   => 6
p:2   => 7
p:3   => 8
p:4   => 9
```

You can bind entire configurations or configuration sections to typed objects, e.g. arrays and lists, or even nested C# objects. This is heavily used when combining configuration with [the options pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-3.1). You can also invoke the binding process manually:

With the above configuration, you could for example access the array at `key3:f3_cachekey:0:p` by retrieving the *configuration section* at that path and binding it to an int array:

```cs
int[] values = configuration.GetSection("key3:f3_cachekey:0:p").Get<int[]>();
```

You can use this to similarly retrieve the other values. Or you can define a full type that matches your JSON structure and bind it to that object type instead:

```cs
CacheKeySP[] values = configuration.GetSection("key3:f3_cachekey").Get<CacheKeySP[]>();
```

This assumes a class definition like this:

```cs
public class CacheKeySP
{
    public int S { get; set; }
    public int[] P { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I see. Now I understood basically how this works. Is there any way to make a dictionary the way I was trying to with this current json structure for `f3_cachekey` object using configuration? or I need to change the json structure little bit to do exactly what I was trying to do? Basically I want to create Dictionary for `f3_cachekey` object.

Comment: I only have those two cases for `f3_cachekey` object. Either combination of `s` and `p` or just an array of `p's`.

Comment: I would recommend you to define a simple but proper type for that, i.e. `class SP { public int S { get; set; } public int[] P { get; set; } }`. And then you can bind the `f3_cachekey` to a `SP[]`.

Comment: hmmm I am kinda confuse on how I will populate that? Do you think you can provide an example which can help me understand on this basis on my code?

Comment: @user1950349 I’ve adjusted my final example to show you a working example. Hope that helps!